# Hibernate Criteria expression

Tags: mysql, hibernate, criteria

How can I convert the following sql query to criteria:

```
select count(*) from table where column >= 'value'
```

I tried this example :

```
Criteria criteria=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                  .createCriteria(RadioCsv.class)        
                  .add(Restrictions.ge("signalstrength", -35))      
                  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                  .add(Projections.count("signalstrength"))           
                  );
```

Comment: whats the problem with your criteria?

Comment: i'm a bigenner in hibernate, i search how to use criteria to have the same result like in sql, thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Integer count = session.createQuery("from table where column >= ?").setParameter(0, value).list().size();
```

Or this:

```
Integer count = session.createQuery("from table where column >="+value).list().size();
```

Comment: thanks it works fine, if i want have the count of column >=value1 and column<= value2, what must i do, thks again (sorry for my english)

Comment: .setParameter(0, value1).setParameter(1, value2) i think is the solution

Comment: try this as well: `Integer count = session.createQuery("from table where column >="+value+" and column<="+value2).list().size();`